# How do I reformat HTML code in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have installed the plug-in "Prettify" so that when I hit ctrl-shift-H it reformats all of my html code. Though there is one small issue I am finding:

```
 <li class="item1"><a class="first" href="http:/www.etcetc.com">Philosophy</a>
</li>

 <li class="item2"><a href="http:/www.etcetc.com">Programs &amp; School Calendar</a>
</li>
```

The closing tag of the li appears on the next line. It has actually caused me problems. Anyone know how to make it so it appears on the end of the line? Much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your home folder, create a file called `.jsbeautifyrc` with the following contents:

```json
{
  "html": {
    "unformatted": ["a", "sub", "sup", "b", "i", "u", "li"]
  }
}
```

You can add to this list as needed if you have other tags that you don't want Prettify to split.

Comment: What do you mean by home folder?

Comment: @user3170967 What operating system are you using?

Comment: @user3170967 your home folder should be `C:\users\YourUserName` where `YourUserName` is your Windows login name. For example, mine is `C:\Users\MattDMo`.